# Generate Section Trailer with Variable Number of Rows [Report Builder]

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a report for which I need to get the number of bank accounts of each type for each team in my baseball league. I need a listing of the team, player, and account, with a subtotal footer that gives the counts of each kind of account for each team, like this:

| Team | Player | Account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yankees | Babe Ruth | Savings |
| Yankees | Lou Gehrig | Other |
| Yankees | Aaron Judge | Loan |
| Yankees | Joe DiMaggio | Savings |
| Yankees | Derek Jeter | Savings |

```
Accounts:

Savings      3
Loan         1
Other        1
Total        5
```

| Team | Player | Account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red Sox | David Ortiz | Other |
| Red Sox | Pedro Martinez | Savings |
| Red Sox | Jackie Bradley Jr. | Other |
| Red Sox | Ted Williams | Savings |
| Red Sox | Pedro Martinez | Savings |

```
Accounts:

Savings      3
Other        2
Total        5
```

So far I've done this by creating hide conditions for each of the rows so that they're only visible when there's an account of the designated type, but that gets cumbersome as the number of Account Types increases, and if I add a new account (say, Checking) the report has to be updated. How would I get this report to generate subtotals that only reference data that's present within the group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the Accounts summary section you could use a table. The design would look like this:
[image]

This would need to be grouped by the Account column so that there is one row per Account value. You can remove borders and format as needed to make it look how you want.

Comment: If I created a second table, would I have to create individual body and summary tables for each team?

Comment: No, you can nest tables :)  So this whole table I described could go in the last row of the initial table. Also, you could simply add a Row Group (adjacent below) instead of messing with nesting at all.